# IComparable and OrderBy. Trying to sort Poker hands with C#

Tags: c#, poker, icomparer

I am attempting to create a simple program that analyzes the poker hands. Given n hands/players and the community cards (Texas hold 'em) I would like to determine the winner(s). However, my test is failing when I have two exact results - it only returns one winner. i.e The hand result contains J J 9 9 K, for both players, but my winners list contains one.

There are a couple reasons why I am posting here. Obviously, the first being is there anything apparent that is wrong here? Is this a good approach to have the sorting implemented (I couldn't see a reason to separate the sorting), is there a better approach and why?

I have a DetermineWinners method that is performing a order on the players' HandResult:

```
var ordered = _players.OrderByDescending(player => player.Result);
var bestHand = ordered.First();
var winners = ordered.Where(s => s.Result == bestHand.Result).ToList();
```

Here is my hand result class:

```
    public class HandResult : IComparable<HandResult>
{
    public Hand WholeCards { get; set; }
    public HandRanking HandRank { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Card> CommunityCards { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Card> UsedCards { get; set; }

    public static bool operator !=(HandResult a, HandResult b)
    {
        if (a == null)
            return b != null;
        if (b == null)
            return true;

        if (a.HandRank != b.HandRank)
            return true;

        //Compare Used Cards
        var aCards = a.UsedCards.Select(s => s.GetCardValue()).ToList();
        var bCards = b.UsedCards.Select(s => s.GetCardValue()).ToList();
        var cardGroup = a.HandRank.GetGrouping();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += cardGroup[i])
        {
            if (aCards[i] != bCards[i])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(HandResult a, HandResult b)
    {
        if ((object)a == null)
            return (object)b == null;
        if ((object)b == null)
            return false;

        if (a.HandRank != b.HandRank)
            return false;

        var aCards = a.UsedCards.Select(s => s.GetCardValue()).ToList();
        var bCards = b.UsedCards.Select(s => s.GetCardValue()).ToList();

        var cardGroup = a.HandRank.GetGrouping();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += cardGroup[i])
        {
            if (aCards[i] != bCards[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator >(HandResult a, HandResult b)
    {
        if ((object)a == null)
            return (object)b != null;
        if ((object)b == null)
            return false;
        if ((object)a == (object)b)
            return false;

        if (a.HandRank != b.HandRank)
            return a.HandRank > b.HandRank;

        if (a == b)
            return false;

        var aCards = a.UsedCards.Select(s => s.GetCardValue()).ToList();
        var bCards = b.UsedCards.Select(s => s.GetCardValue()).ToList();

        var cardGroup = a.HandRank.GetGrouping();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += cardGroup[i])
        {
            if (aCards[i] != bCards[i])
            {
                return aCards[i] > bCards[i];
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator <(HandResult a, HandResult b)
    {
        if ((object)a == null)
            return (object)b == null;
        if ((object)b == null)
            return true;
        if ((object)a == (object)b)
            return false;

        if (a.HandRank != b.HandRank)
            return a.HandRank < b.HandRank;

        var aCards = a.UsedCards.Select(s => s.GetCardValue()).ToList();
        var bCards = b.UsedCards.Select(s => s.GetCardValue()).ToList();

        var cardGroup = a.HandRank.GetGrouping();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += cardGroup[i])
        {
            if (aCards[i] != bCards[i])
                return aCards[i] < bCards[i];
        }

        return false;
    }

    #region IComparable<HandResult> Members

    public int CompareTo(HandResult other)
    {
        if (this == null)
            return other == null ? 0 : -1;
        if (other == null)
            return 1;

        if (this == other)
            return 0;
        if (this > other)
            return 1;

        return -1;
    }

    #endregion

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this == (HandResult)obj;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var result = 0;

        result = (result * 397) ^ (int)this.HandRank;

        foreach (var card in this.UsedCards)
        {
            result = (result * 397) ^ card.GetHashCode();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The GetCardResult method simply returns an integer representation of the card, i.e 1 through 14. Here is the HandRanking enum:

```
public enum HandRanking
{
    HighCard,
    Pair,
    TwoPair,
    ThreeOfAKind,
    Straight,
    Flush,
    FullHouse,
    FourOfAKind,
    StraightFlush,
    RoyalFlush
}
```

This is the GetGrouping extension on the HandRanking enum. It is used to help iterate through the cards when comparing values:

```
    internal static int[] GetGrouping(this HandRanking rank)
    {
        switch (rank)
        {
            case HandRanking.Pair:
                return new int[] { 2, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
            case HandRanking.TwoPair:
                return new int[] { 2, 0, 2, 0, 1 };
            case HandRanking.ThreeOfAKind:
                return new int[] { 3, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
            case HandRanking.FullHouse:
                return new int[] { 3, 0, 0, 2, 0 };
            case HandRanking.FourOfAKind:
                return new int[] { 4, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            default:
                return new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        }
    }
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** My tests for CompareTo_Equal, CompareTo_LessThan and CompareTo_GreaterThan (which uses my operator overloads) succeed with results: 0, -1 and 1, respectively. I am lead to believe it's a problem with my Linq.OrderByDescending implementation. I would of thought this just uses the CompareTo implemenation, am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The comparison provided by `IComparable` (you should use the generic version `IComparable<T>` anyway) is solely represented through the interface method `int CompareTo(IComparable other)` whose result is

- > 0 if the current object is greater than `other`
- < 0 if the current object is less than `other`
- = 0 for equality

The overloaded comparison operators don't matter for any code that relies on `IComparable`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It seems I did not paste my code properly. I edited my post to reflect the full HandResult class, I have also used the Generic <T> version of IComparable. That said, my test is still failing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select the Winners by choosing those with Results equal to the best hand's Result, but that is only true when the hands are *exactly* the same (I think, I'm having trouble seeing the whole picture without knowing what exactly is in cardGroup[i].

Are you certain the hands you expect to be identical are actually identical (as in same suit even)?

And then I would also suggest that you implement most of your operator overloads in terms of other operators.  For example, != could be implemented as !(==) (inverting the result of calling the == operator, rather than reimplementing the whole set of conditionals - right now, if you change the way Equals is determined you'll have to duplicate those changes in !=)

Comment: I see your original code was edited while I typed my answer, but I'm afraid I don't have time at the moment to review it and update my answer in turn.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. Sorry about the code edit, it wasn't all there before. Yes, the winners are determined by the players with the bestHand. I have overriden the .Equals and == operator to check the values of the cards, so it excludes the suites.

The cardGroup[i] section only hits when then HandRank is the same, in which case it will iterate through the values and make the comparison on the 5 cards that make the hand.